# OR tools Sports Scheduling problem and modeling constraints

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

I'm enjoying learning about or-tools, and hope someone can help me out a bit.  I've got a problem that's a bit like the nurse-scheduling problem, but instead it's for sports-scheduling.  Here's what I've got so far to generate the combinations of possible games.

```
# Create schedule variables
for h in range(divisions):
    for i in range(teams_per_division):
        for j in range(i+1, teams_per_division):
            for k in range(weeks):
                for l in range(venues):
                    schedule[h, i, j, k, l] = model.NewBoolVar( f"schedule_div{h}_team{i}_team{j}_week{k}_venue{l}")
```

The constraints I'm trying to add are:

- A team plays once per week (regardless of whether it's in position 'i' or 'j', and irrespective of 'venue'.)
- A venue, l, has a max capacity of 'games' it can host in any given week, k.
- And so on.

So far, I've tried introducing a new variable, 'played', like this:
`played[h, i, k, l] = model.NewBoolVar( f"played_div{h}_team{i}_week{k}_venue{l}")`

but I'm having trouble linking this 'played' to 'schedule', and then modeling the constraints.

Any and all help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I figured it out.

First I created a new variable like so:

```
for h in range(divisions):
    for i in range(teams_per_division):
        for k in range(weeks):
            weekPlayed[h, i, k] = model.NewIntVar( 0, 10, f"played_div{h}_team{i}_week{k}")
            for l in range(venues):
                played[h, i, k, l] = model.NewBoolVar( f"played_div{h}_team{i}_week{k}_venue{l}")
```

Now, with the 'played' variable, I could just increment these counters during schedule-creation, like so (note that both i and j are incremented):

```
...
                    # Increment key counters
                    weekPlayed[h, i, k] = weekPlayed[h, i, k] + schedule[h, i, j, k, l]
                    weekPlayed[h, j, k] = weekPlayed[h, j, k] + schedule[h, i, j, k, l]
```

Finally, the needed constraint:

```
# Each team plays once per week
for h in range(divisions):
    for i in range(teams_per_division):
        for k in range(weeks):
            model.Add(weekPlayed[h, i, k] <= 1)
```

I hope this is helpful to someone else trying to link offshoot variables, and then constrain them independently.

Comment: I don't think this is going to work for you.  You can't just treat the variables as "counters" and increment them.  They are all unknowns and passed to the solver and must be statically evaluated in the course of the solve...  meaning there is no increment scheme that works.